# NGINX rewrite rule to remove leading www for Vanity URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've searched everywhere and although there are 1000s of examples of how to strip a leading www from a URL using NGINX rewrite rules, I've yet to find an example of how to strip the leading 'www' from a vanity url.

For example, convert '*www.fred.mysite.com*' to '*fred.mysite.com*'

Can you share an example of how this should work in an nginx rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do it is with a 2nd serverblock as follows:

```
server {
  listen [::]:80; listen 80;
  server_name www.fred.mysite.com;
  return 301 $scheme://fred.mysite.com$request_uri;
} 

server {
  listen [::]:80; listen 80;
  server_name fred.mysite.com;

  #your site setup goes here
}
```

though you probably want to use "server_name *.fred.mysite.com;" in the 1st serverblock just to catch every possible extra prefix including misspellings